# Getting latitud - longitud data from route create on Here Maps - traffic viewer

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

How can i get lat - long from a specific corridor created on traffic viewer

if i need the lat-long from point A start to point B finished , were is that information that i need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must consider the Geo-coding in order to convert the place name into geo coordinates form the html page itself.

Comment: thks , but how can i get lat-long from traffic viewer?

Comment: It is not possible to pick lat-long from traffic viewer as per the current functionality in traffic viewer.

Comment: ok from were you get the lat-long , from corridor , route ? in your example docsite put exam:

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json
?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
&waypoint0=geo!52.5,13.4
&waypoint1=geo!52.5,13.45
&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled